# Sum of probabilities is infinite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm stucked solving this problem:

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables
>   with exponential distribution and $\lambda=1$. Show that
>   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}=1\ a.s$$

So 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}=1\ a.s\Leftrightarrow P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}=1)=1$$

Since we are looking at i.i.d. random variables Borel-Cantelli say that this can only be true if
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty P(\frac{X_n}{\ln(n)}=1)=\infty$$
How do I show this last equality?

Comment: Unless they defined $P$ very strangely, there's an error in that question. ​ A probability is either a real number or undefined, not something that can be true or false. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes you are right. That $P$ should't be there. I'm very sorry.

Comment: Now, the $P$s on your $\implies$ line shouldn't be there, and even with them removed, I don't see why that line should hold. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The line should say, if the limes superior of that sequence is equal to $1$ a.s. then this implies that $P(\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}X_n=\ln(n))=1$. I hope it's better now. I'm sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: If we try to do $\sum(1)$ then obviously it should equal $\infty$, right? (Sorry if this isn't helpful)

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong about the $P$ on the right of that implication. ​ However, the implication you have won't necessarily hold. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: As a general comment on proof strategy, if you have to prove a statement $Q$, implications like "$Q\implies$ something" are not generally useful. I would look instead for "something $\implies Q$". If the "something" and $Q$ are actually equivalent, the arrow could go either way and you just want to be sure to show it in the direction you need.

Comment: @DavidK I'm a little bit confused. Why does the right side of the implication not show almost sure convergence? I thought almost sure convergence is defined as $P(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n = X) = 1$?

Comment: I'm not talking about which of your statements is true. I'm talking about what your statements _say._ Your first implication is useless here, because the arrow is pointing in the direction _away_ from the thing you want to prove. Is the statement true if you reverse the arrow? If so, then that's what you should write.

Comment: @DavidK I changed it to an equivalent arrow, I hope it's now better. But I'm still confused whether it is the same, since Ricky Demer's comment say's that the implication won't necessarily hold, but I thought that I just rearranged the terms.

Comment: @MarcE Let's take out the probability here for a second. Do you see the issue with the statement that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n} = 1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+1} = n?$$ Further, I believe that you probably want the $X_n$ in your limsup to be the *maximum* of $n$ i.i.d. exponential random variables with mean 1.

Comment: @D Poole: the statement is true without a maximum, so I don't see the need to introduce one.

Comment: @DPoole a yes, I now see the problem. Thank you. So correct way would be $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{\ln (n)}=1\Leftrightarrow P(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{\ln (n)} = 1)=1$$

Comment: @D.Thomine Ahh yes. I was making it harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guideline. Some details are left as smaller exercises, but I really encourage you to fill them up. I'll first recall how to prove that a sequence of random variables converges almost surely, before adapting the argument to the limsups.

**Convergence of sequences of random variables**

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$. We say that $\lim_{n \to + \infty} a_n = \ell$ if and only if:

$$\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_+^*, \ \exists N \geq 0 : \ \forall n \geq N, \ |a_n-\ell| \leq \varepsilon.$$

Note that, in the definition, we may require without loss of generality that $\varepsilon$ be a positive rational (or even that $\varepsilon = 1/M$ for some integer $M$).

Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables, and let $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim_{n \to + \infty} Y_n = \ell$ almost surely if and only if

$$\left[ \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_+^*, \ \exists N \geq 0 : \ \forall n \geq N, \ |Y_n-\ell| \leq \varepsilon \right] \ \text{almost surely}.$$

For $\varepsilon > 0$, let $A_\varepsilon$ be the set of sequences $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\exists N \geq 0 : \ \forall n \geq N, \ |Y_n-\ell| \leq \varepsilon$. Then

$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} Y_n = \ell \Leftrightarrow (Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} A_\varepsilon = \bigcap_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+^*} A_\varepsilon.$$

Since the RHS is a countable intersection of measurable sets, it has full measure if and only if each set has full measure. Hence:

$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} Y_n = \ell \ \text{a.s.} \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+^*, \ \left[ (Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in A_\varepsilon \ \text{a.s.} \right].$$

Finally, I can replace the condition $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+^*, \ \left[ (Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in A_\varepsilon \ \text{a.s.} \right]$ by the condition $\forall \varepsilon >0, \ \left[ (Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in A_\varepsilon \ \text{a.s.} \right]$, which is implied by the LHS above, and implies the RHS.

Hence, is you want to prove that a sequence of random variables almost surely converges to some constant $\ell$, the most fundamental method is to fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$, and then to prove that $A_\varepsilon$ has full measure, or in other words that almost surely, there exists $N \geq 0$ such that $|X_n-\ell| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. We have managed to get the "almost surely" *inside* the "for all $\varepsilon > 0$, which is very important and not completely obvious (until you get used to it).

**Convergence of sequences of random variables**

To goal of the section above was to remind you of something you should have already seen, so that what follows does not drops from nowhere.

You want to compute a limsup instead of a mere limit. It shall be quite convenient to use the following characterization of the limsup (**left as an exercise**). Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\limsup_{n \to + \infty} a_n = \ell$ if and only if:

$$\forall \varepsilon >0, \ \{n: \ a_n >\ell+\varepsilon\} \text{ is finite and } \{n: \ a_n >\ell-\varepsilon\} \text{ is infinite.}$$

Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Using the same trick as in the first section (again, the details are **left as an exercise**),

$$\limsup_{n \to + \infty} Y_n = \ell \ \text{a.s.} \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0, \ \left[ \{n: \ Y_n >\ell+\varepsilon\} \text{ is finite and } \{n: \ X_n >\ell-\varepsilon\} \text{ is infinite a.s.} \right].$$

Finally, by a usual characterization of the limsup and liminf of sets, $\{n: \ Y_n >\ell+\varepsilon\}$ is finite if and only if

$$(Y_n)_{n \geq 0} \notin \limsup_{n \geq 0} \ \{Y_n >\ell+\varepsilon\},$$

and $\{n: \ Y_n >\ell-\varepsilon\}$ is infinite if and only if

$$(Y_n)_{n \geq 0} \in \limsup_{n \geq 0} \ \{Y_n >\ell-\varepsilon\}.$$

So what you need to prove is that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$,

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \geq 0} \ \{Y_n >\ell+\varepsilon\}\right) = 0 \text{ and } \mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \geq 0} \ \{Y_n >\ell-\varepsilon\}\right) = 1.$$

Choose wisely the sequence $(Y_n)_{n \geq 0}$ and the constant $\ell$, use Borel-Cantelli's lemma, and you should be able to prove the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot to understand it better. Thank you so much.